# How to add framework to Xcode project via cmake correctly?

Tags: xcode, cmake

I am converting old project that was set up manually via Xcode and I encountered the problem that I could not add libraries to Framework folder of the project.
This is how the Frameworks part of the original project looks in Xcode:

[image]

This is the cmake script that I made thus far (its incomplete, but I want to get at least something before continuing):

```
    set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY BOTH)

    find_library(LIB_RADEON_IMAGE_FILTERS NAMES libRadeonImageFilters.1.7.1.dylib PATHS "../RadeonProImageProcessingSDK/OSX/Dynamic")
    if (NOT LIB_RADEON_IMAGE_FILTERS)
        message(FATAL_ERROR "libRadeonImageFilters not found")
    endif()
    
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} -framework ${LIB_RADEON_IMAGE_FILTERS})
    
    find_library(LIB_OPEN_IMAGE NAMES libOpenImageIO.1.6.dylib PATHS "../RadeonProRenderSharedComponents/OpenImageIO/OSX/bin")
    if (NOT LIB_RADEON_IMAGE_FILTERS)
        message(FATAL_ERROR "libOpenImageIO not found")
    endif()
    
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} -framework ${LIB_OPEN_IMAGE})
```

I'm not getting any error during project generation (thus I believe cmake finds libraries successfully), however in the generated project both "Frameworks" folder and paths to frameworks are empty, and when I try to build the project I get the following error:

```
ld: framework not found /Users/DMotor/Documents/dev/RadeonProRenderMayaPlugin/RadeonProImageProcessingSDK/OSX/Dynamic/libRadeonImageFilters.1.7.1.dylib
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

<s>I case that matters, cmake version I have on my Mac is 3.19.5</s> (it has an old OS version as well).
Tried with 3.26.4 and got the same result.

How to overcome this problem?